# Is it possible to skip html tags using jquery and split method?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using `split` to insert javascript generated text into a html text, but I need to skip the parts like html tags `</><\>`, so after searching a lot, I found this:

```
var = var.replace(/<\/?[\w#"'-=:; {},.\r\n]+\/?>/g, '\n');
```

the problem is that it doesn't skip the tags or anything that is specified in that variable, it actually replaces the tags with a blank space.

What I need to achieve is, example:

`<script>random javascript</script><p>my text</p> --- New text that needs to be inserted ---`

What's currently happening:

`my text</p> --- New text that needs to be inserted ---`

As you can see, the first tags (The javascript) are not being skiped, they are being stripped.

What method should I use instead of replace?

Comment: Never use regex for HTML. For the rest of your question, for me it's completely unclear what you're asking.

Comment: What do you suggest?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying, but JavaScript / jQuery DOM methods are the way to go for DOM manipulations

Comment: Suggest that you clarify what you are trying to do, rather than the problem you have with the current way you are trying to do it.  Refer to [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Given your example, you would do:  `$("p").append("--- New text---")` but I suspect your actual issue is somewhat more complicated.

Comment: In your `replace` statement, you "replace" opening tags with a newline "\n" - hence "replaces the tags with blank space" - ofc it will, that's what you told it to do - and why @Michael rightly says don't use regex for html.   jquery already "splits" all the html tags for you, so no need to "jquery and split".

Comment: First, never call a variable with 'var' name. Second, never use regex to DOM purposes. Third, give to your p tag an id, and modify it's contents with document.getElementById("your p tag id") or something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> to insert javascript generated text into a html text
>
> What I need to achieve is, example:
>
> `<script>random javascript</script><p>my text</p> --- New text that > needs to be inserted ---`

Try using `document.createTextNode()` , `.insertAfter()`

```js
var text = document.createTextNode("--- New text that needs to be inserted ---");
$(text).insertAfter("p:contains(my text)")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>var str = "random javascript"</script><p>my text</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you will need to use it pretty frequently, than I suggest to create some kind of handler for that. We can make it act like an extremally tiny framework. You can have a custom tag, which will replace it's value right in place where it was.

```js
let js = [...document.getElementsByTagName('js')];
js.map(i => {
  let frequency = i.getAttribute('frequency');
  let innerHTML = i.innerHTML;
  let condition = i.getAttribute('stop-if');
  if (frequency && frequency.length != 0) {
    let parent = i.parentNode;
    let index = [...parent.children].indexOf(i);
    i.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', `<output>${eval(innerHTML)}</output>`);
    i.remove();
    if (condition && eval(condition)) {
      return;
    } 
    let el = parent.children[index];
    let interval = setInterval(() => {
      if (condition && eval(condition)) {
        clearInterval(interval);
      } 
      el.innerHTML = `${eval(innerHTML)}`
    }, frequency|0)
  }
  else i.outerHTML = `<output>${eval(innerHTML)}</output>`
})
```

```css
js {
  visibility: hidden;
  font-size: 0;
}
js::after {
  font-size: 1rem;
  content: attr(default);
  visibility: visible
}
```

```html
<js frequency="1000" stop-if="" default="">`New text that needs to be inserted, or a JavaScript variable, function call, or any other valid JavaScript expression.`</js>
```

It is extremally simple, and gets all  custom tags, and just replaces them by the value they return. It also supports `frequency`, meaning, that your code can repeat itself after specific amount of miliseconds, and you have `stop-if` attribute, which will stop the execution of the process once the condition is true. The `default` value is an optional value for your page to show with the use of CSS `::after` pseudo-element.